# How to links and refer to self in swagger docs?

Tags: hyperlink, swagger, openapi, self-reference

If I have a `doc/api` endpoint that should point to the current swagger doc, how should the self-referring be done for Swagger with OpenAPI 3.0.0?

For example, given

```
openapi: 3.0.0
servers:
  - url: http://hello-world.com
info:
  description: |-
    Hello World!
  version: "4"
  title: Hello World

components:
  schemas:
    SwaggerDoc:
      type: object
      properties:
        address:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/SwaggerDoc'

paths:
  /docs/api:
    get:
      summary: Swagger Documentation (HTML)
      tags:
        - Service Information
      responses:
        '200':
          description: HTML Document of RIT Translate API
          content:
            'text/html':
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/SwaggerDoc'
        '503':
          description: The server is not ready.
```

And the output from https://editor.swagger.io shows:

[image]

On the right of the response section under `Links`, it shows "No links`. **Is it possible to add the link to link to self under that link?**

**And for the 503, how should I link it to another static error page?**

Comment: Does `/docs/api` point to the OpenAPI YAML/JSON file or to Swagger UI?

Comment: It should point to the swagger UI. But is it possible to point to the swagger UI and also point it to also export the yaml/json file?

Comment: Did you get any progress here?